# FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I use this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04) with Python 3.5, Django 1.9, Linux Mint and PostgreSQL 9.3. But when I try "manage.py migrate" I have an error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myprojectuser"
```

My database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'myproject',
    'USER': 'myprojectuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
}}
```

Comment: Is the password the correct one? Are you able to login in psql using the same credentials?

Comment: When I type "psql -d myproject -U myprojectuser" I have error: 'psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "myprojectuser"'

Comment: I think this http://askubuntu.com/questions/820792/peer-authentication-failed-for-user-with-all-privileges-in-postgres-9-5 will solve your problem

Comment: Now I can login in psql using this username and password. But when I make 'manage.py migrate' I have the same error: password authentication failed for user "myprojectuser"

Comment: You can try with database url like: `'default':  "postgres://myprojectuser:password@127.0.0.1:5432/myproject"`

Comment: It didn't help me

Comment: It's still giving the same error?

Comment: No. Now it's " AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault' "

Comment: Where is the error occurring? Kindly provide the stack trace

Comment: My database settings: DATABASES = { 'default': "postgres://myuser:password@127.0.0.1:5432/myproject" } When I do 'migrate': `File "/data/work/virtualenvs/delivery/lib/python3.5/site-packages‌​/django/db/utils.py"‌​, line 181, in ensure_defaults conn.setdefault('ATOMIC_REQUESTS', False) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault' `

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fTJBLi84

Comment: Add `DATABASES['default']['ATOMIC_REQUESTS'] = False` below the `DATABASES` line

Comment: I have this error: `File "/data/work/virtualenvs/delivery/src/delivery/delivery/settings.py", line 81, in <module>
    DATABASES['default']['ATOMIC_REQUESTS'] = False
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: Sorry about that. the database url requires `environ` http://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#django-environ

Answer (score 1):

its fairly self-explanatory, are the database password setting and the postgres user setting equal?

open a terminal and `sudo -i -u postgres psql` then do `alter user myprojectuser with encrypted password xxxxx;`
set password equal to the value of password in your settings dict

```
'default': {
'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
}
```

Comment: its odd! I suggest you do a  fresh start